# Application request limit while executing Fql

Tags: facebook-fql

We are getting the following error while making API calls

```
<error_code>4</error_code>
<error_msg>Application request limit reached</error_msg>
```

When we check the insights we are way below the allowed call, we have made only 1 million calls in a months time. This specially happens when we are firing FQL queries, how can we solve this?

Regards,

Ayush